# JSON returning as undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jquery

Hello I have an ajax request that submits a form and sends and email, if the email is submitted successfully, I encode a PHP array that looks like this,

`$success = array("state" => "Email Sent");`

I am then checking the state of `data` in my ajax request to see if `state` matches "Email Sent" however when I `alert(data)` i get undefined, what am I doing wrong? Below is my javascript,

```
$.ajax({
                    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/callback",
                    data: $("#callback").serialize(),
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    success: function(data){
                        $("#fancybox-content div").html(data);
                        alert(data.state);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: did you `json_encode($success)` before output?

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the html value of the 'fancybox-content' div.
$('#fancybox-content').html();

Answer (score 0):

If you alert is failing then are you sure your json is valid? Can you paste it into your question. You can validate it here online at [JsonLint](http://www.jsonlint.com/).

Answer (score 0):

how do you return the `$succes` array?
You should `echo` the array in a way that would preserve it's format and would be understandable to javascript (not `print_r` or `var_dump`):

```
echo json_decode($success);
```

that will return a json string representing your php array, which js automatically converts into an object.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
json_decode($success, true);
```

> When TRUE, returned objects will be  converted into associative arrays.