# AJAX json returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web

I have simple ajax query

```
$.ajax(
{
    url:'ADMPANEL_POST.php',
    type:'POST',
    data:{'z':'1'},
    dataType:'json',
    success:function (result) {
        alert( "Data recieved: " + result.x );
        $('#result').append(result.x);
    }
});
```

in ADMPANEL_POST.php i try to get z=1 and have appropriate handler, and i expect to return data_str using json_encode to ajax success function

```
if(isset($_POST['z'])) 
{
    $init_x = 'test';
    $data_str[] = array('x' => $init_x);
    if($_POST['z']=='1') {
        echo json_encode($data_str, true);
    }
}
```

However i recieve undefined value of data.x in alert message. Can't figure out what is the problem. Thanks.
P.S.: saw this, but it didn't help [JSON returning as undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634436/json-returning-as-undefined)

Comment: Please try to below line:
alert( "Data recieved: " + result );
        $('#result').append(result);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your format is wrong, if you want `result.x == 'test'` use  `$data_str = array('x' => $init_x);`.